# Every second value from table - sql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Suppose, I have some table like

```
| id | user_id | value |
|:---|:-------:| -----:|
|   1|        1|      a|
|   2|        1|      b|
|   3|        1|      c|
|   4|        2|      d|
|   5|        2|      e|
|   6|        3|      f|
|   7|        4|      g|
|   8|        4|      h|
```

So I need print all second values for every user, for example

```
| id | user_id | value |
|:---|:-------:| -----:|
|   2|        1|      b|
|   5|        2|      e|
|   8|        4|      h|
```

So, how can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried and what happened? What constitutes the second value (what are you ordering by)?

Comment: Second is based on ordering so is the ordering for a `user_id` to be by `id` or `value`. Your expected output is not clear on this.

Comment: In my case, every second value means the following:

We take every user (from user_id). So user with id 1 have values a, b and c, we need to print b. User with id 2 have values d and e - so we print e. And finally user with id 4 have values g and h - and we are printing h.

Comment: @PrintScreenSys  Incidently: before the comment I had little problem understanding your question.

Comment: Still did not answer the question. Right now `id`(not `user_id`) and `value` share the same ordering in that the numeric order of `id` matches the alphabetic order of `value'. It  is not clear to me if that will always be the case. Nor is it clear whether you want second by the order of `value` or by order of `id` or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an inline view and an analytic to generate a row number for each user_ID ordered by ID and then simply select where row number = 2.

```
SELECT ID, user_ID, Value
FROM (SELECT ID, user_ID, Value, Row_number() over (partition by user_ID order by ID) RN
      FROM table) InLineTable
WHERE RN=2
```

or use a common table expression to do the same

essentially what the row number does is for each user_Id it counts by 1 for each ID. it restarts for each new user_ID.  Since we order by ID, we always get the 2nd ID.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT ID, user_ID, Value, Row_number() over (partition by user_ID 
         order by ID) RN
         FROM table)
SELECT ID, user_ID, Value
FROM CTE
WHERE RN=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rank in postgres such as the following:

```
    select id, user_id, value
    from (
        select id, user_id, value, 
        rank() over (partition by user_id order by id) as u_rank
        from t1
        )z
    where u_rank = 2
```

Output:

```
    id  user_id value
    2   1       b
    5   2       e
    8   4       h
```